# RxJS / Angular: Capture valueChanges of FormControl before subscribing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I try to create an observable from the values emitted by the `FormControls.valueChanges` observable.
The observable is created in the `ngOnInit` method as follows:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myObservable$ = combineLatest([
      this.formControl1.valueChanges, 
      this.formControl2.valueChanges
    ]).pipe(
      map(([v1, v2]) => parseInt(v1, 10) + parseInt(v2, 10))
    );

    this.isLoading = true;

    this.loadData().subscribe({
      next: result => {
        this.formControl1.setValue(result[0]);
        this.formControl2.setValue(result[1]);
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
    });
  }
```

The observable gets subscribed to after `isLoading` is set to false:

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">{{ myObservable$ | async }}</div>
```

So in this case `myObservable$` will only start emitting values after `formControl1` and `formControl2` changed manually, since the first emissions of `valueChanges` happen before this observable is subscribed to.

You could write a pretty verbose solution for this:

```
this.myObservable$ = defer(() => combineLatest([
   this.formControl1.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.formControl1.value)), 
   this.formControl2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.formControl2.value))
])).pipe(
   map(([v1, v2]) => parseInt(v1, 10) + parseInt(v2, 10))
);
```

Is there maybe a prettier solution to this?

(https://angular-ivy-n1gwvk.stackblitz.io is the StackBlitz for a minimal example)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following thing in the template. Also verbose-ish, but it's another way of doing it. Otherwise the `startWith` is a proper solution to this issue:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ value: (myObservable$ | async) } as my">
  <div *ngIf="!isLoading">{{ my.value }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

---

Another way would be to subscribe to it and use `shareReplay`:

```
isLoading: true;

readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myObservable$ = combineLatest([
    this.formControl1.valueChanges, 
    this.formControl2.valueChanges
  ]).pipe(
    map(([v1, v2]) => parseInt(v1, 10) + parseInt(v2, 10)),
    shareReplay(1),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  );

  this.myObservable$.subscribe();

  this.loadData().subscribe({
    next: result => {
      this.formControl1.setValue(result[0]);
      this.formControl2.setValue(result[1]);
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to extract some helper sand try take out some repetition.

```
// Helpers

const getControlValueStream = (({ control, valueChanges }): FormControl) => valueChanges.pipe(startWith(value));

const sumNumbers = (numbers: number[]) => numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

```
// Component

const controls = [this.formControl1, this.formControl2];
const valueStreams = controls.map(getControlValueStream);

combineLatest(...valueStreams).pipe(
  map(values => values.map(value => parseInt(value, 10))),
  map(sumNumbers),
);
```

You or your team may find this to be less readable however, which is a fair point - prettiness should be balanced with maintainability.